# Hindi speech recognition

Tags: c#

Using Microsoft Speech API I am able to recognize an English word. I have created a table in `SQL server` which stores Hindi Unicode words corresponding to an English word. Based on the matched word I am able to pick the Hindi counterpart; e.g I have stored words "main", "ja", "raha", "hun". When the recognizer recognizes the speech as "main" it fetches the corresponding Hindi word.

My logic is working but it has very low accuracy. My microphone is of good quality.
Does anybody know a better approach for Hindi speech recognition which provides more accuracy in any technology?

Comment: All good speech engines I'v used have required some tuning and configuration to allow the program to match words accurately to the voice and accent of the speaker. You may find that you need to go down this route as well.

Comment: I have done tuning but problem is of similar words. Have you ever used hindi speech recognition?

Comment: A speech recognizer needs to be tuned to the language, done by an installable language pack.  Afaik, American English, British English, Canadian French, Spanish and German are available.  The tonal languages of East Asia are missing, surely a technical problem.  Getting vendors to target Hindi is a chronic problem, it probably requires a pretty drastic change in copyright protection practices to ever go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

use google speech recognition which recognize hindi phrase in english words that is hinglish, first go to google developer console and registered your and get api key so that you can use google cloud speech services in your app.